# 7zip - specifying recursive mode and compression type

Tags: python, 7zip

I am using a batch script to invoke 7zip from cmdline. I would like to specify recursive mode AND include a compression type. Invoking 7zip with Python by calling the following code:

```
subprocess.call(['7z', 'a', 'dsym.7z', _config.AF_CONFIG_BIN_PATH + "\\*.dsym", '-r -mx3'])
```

If i try to specify -mx3 (7zip compression type switch), I get an error:

```
7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Command Line Error:
Unsupported command:
a -r -mx1
```

I have tried the following commands:

```
7z a dsym.7z long_path_to_files\\*.dsym -r -mx3

7z a -r -mx3 dsym.7z long_path_to_files\\*.dsym
```

Works just fine if I remove the '-r' switch, but I need to have it. How can I do this? :)

Comment: Please show *exactly* how you're specifying it `-mx3` in the case that fails. In a separate list element? In the same element as something else already given? Code samples should be a [mcve] -- the shortest thing able to reproduce the issue with a simple copy-and-paste, if at all possible.

Comment: Charles, updated the description

Comment: Probably more suitable to superuser?

Comment: already running script as Administrator, on a Windows machine.

Comment: Oh, *from commandline*? I thought you were asking how to do that in Python. Why is this tagged as a python question if you want to know how to use a command line tool from the command line? (Indeed, I wouldn't even call it a Stack Overflow question at all).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need `'long_path_to_files/*.dsym'` (add the slash before the star). At least that works for me.

Comment: If I do that, it fails completely. See the description again. The problem is specifying -mx#, if I remove just that parameter the command executes as expected

Comment: This command works for me on Windows 10 in cmd.exe: `7z a -r -mx3 foo.7z "src/scons/*.py"`. I have 7z.exe version 18.05.

Comment: That works and got me going to fix the issue. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in the Python script.

Correct invocation is:

```
subprocess.call(['7z', 'a', '-r', '-mx3', 'dsym.7z', _config.AF_CONFIG_BIN_PATH + "\\*.dsym"])
```